# how to write a Bash function that confirms the value of an existing variable with a user

Tags: bash, function, variables, confirm, indirection

I have a large number of configuration variables for which I want users to issue confirmation of the values. So, there could be some variable specifying a run number in existence and I want the script to ask the user if the current value of the variable is ok. If the user responds that the value is not ok, the script requests a new value and assigns it to the variable.

I have made an initial attempt at a function for doing this, but there is some difficulty with its running; it stalls. I would value some assistance in solving the problem and also any criticisms of the approach I'm using. The code is as follows:

```
confirmVariableValue(){
    variableName="${1}"
    variableValue="${!variableName}"
    while [[ "${userInput}" != "n" && "${userInput}" != "y" ]]; do
        echo "variable "${variableName}" value: "${variableValue}""
        echo "Is this correct? (y: continue / n: change it / other: exit)"
        read userInput
        # Make the user input lowercase.
        userInput="$(echo "${userInput}" | sed 's/\(.*\)/\L\1/')"
        # If the user input is "n", request a new value for the variable. If the
        # user input is anything other than "y" or "n", exit. If the user input
        # is "y", then the user confirmation loop ends.
        if [[ "${userInput}" == "n" ]]; then
            echo "enter variable "${variableName}" value:"
            read variableValue
        elif [[ "${userInput}" != "y" && "${userInput}" != "n" ]]; then
            echo "terminating"
            exit 0
        fi
    done
    echo "${variableValue}"
}

myVariable="run_2014-09-23T1909"
echo "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "initial variable value: "${myVariable}""
myVariable="$(confirmVariableValue "myVariable")"
echo "final variable value: "${myVariable}""
echo "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review.

Comment: No. The code does not work. I am not sure why and am requesting assistance.

Comment: @chepner: Only part is code review.  There is an error report: "it stalls".

Comment: *Where* does it stall? Does the program just stop running, or does it never stop asking for confirmation regardless of the input, or what?

Comment: Part of the problem is the way the function returns a value. Technically, all printouts from the function are accepted as having been 'returned' by the function. However, the stall occurs when the function is called. I think this is because it is waiting for a user response but there is no printout while it does this. If you run the code, the behaviour should be observable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
myVariable="$(confirmVariableValue "myVariable")"
```

your questions, like

```
    echo "Is this correct? (y: continue / n: change it / other: exit)"
```

are going into the `myVariable` and not to the screen.

Try print questions to STDERR, or any other file-descriptor but STDOUT.

*Opinion based comment*: I would be unhappy with such config-script. It is way too chatty. For me is better:

- print out the description and the default value
- and ask `Press Enter for confirm or enter a new value or <something> for exit>`

You can also, use the following technique:

- use the bash `readline` library for the `read` command with `-e`
- use the `-i value` for set the default value for the editing
- use the `printf -v variable` to print into variable, so you don't need to use `var=$(...)` nor any (potentially) dangerous eval...

example:

```
err() { echo "$@" >&2; return 1; }

getval() {
    while :
    do
        read -e -i "${!1}" -p "$1>" inp
        case "$inp" in
            Q|q) err "Quitting...." || return 1 ;;
            "") err "Must enter some value" ;;
            *)
                #validate the input here

                #and print the new value into the variable
                printf -v "$1" "%s" "$inp"
                return 0
                ;;
        esac
    done
}

somevariable=val1
anotherone=val2
x=val3

for var in somevariable anotherone x
do
    getval "$var" || exit 
    echo "new value for $var is: =${!var}="
done
```

Comment: Ooh, I didn't know about `printf -v`.  That's awesome!

Comment: Ah, that's very nifty. Thank you for your clear explanation of the problem and for a solution that is not only more user-friendly, but more efficient in code.

Answer (score 1):

I would not have them answer "Yes" then type in the new value.  Just have them type in the new value if they want one, or leave it blank to accept the default.

This little function lets you set multiple variables in one call:

```
function confirm() {
    echo "Confirming values for several variables."

    for var; do
        read -p "$var = ${!var} ... leave blank to accept or enter a new value: "
        case $REPLY in
        "") # empty use default
            ;;
        *) # not empty, set the variable using printf -v
            printf -v "$var" "$REPLY"
            ;;
        esac
    done
}
```

Used like so:

```
$ foo='foo_default_value'
$ bar='default_for_bar'
$ confirm foo bar
Confirming values for several variables.

foo = foo_default_value ... leave blank to accept or enter a new value: bar
bar = default_for_bar ... leave blank to accept or enter a new value:

foo=[bar], bar=[default_for_bar]
```

Of course, if blank can be a default, then you would need to account for that, like @jm666 use of `read -i`.

Comment: using `eval` when the user enters inputs could be a bit dangerous... (human factor, mistakes...)

Comment: @jm666: Yep.  Now that I know about `printf -v` (thanks for the tip!), I've eliminated pretty much the last reasonable use of `eval`.

Comment: :) check also the `declare` (typeset). Also allows set the variable. happy to helped :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your user-friendliness recommendations and for your clean code that can cope with multiple variables well.